# get value of var in jQuery

Tags: jquery, var

is it possible to get  the var codeError by function ? I need to post this value to a variable $code in php.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cognome').bind( 'blur',  function(){
        var cog = $(this).val();
        if(cog == "" || cog.length<=2) {
            $('#chkCognome' ).addClass("invalid").removeClass("valid"); 

            var codeError=1;
        } else {
            $('#chkCognome').addClass("valid").removeClass("invalid");  

            var codeError=0;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare it outside the scope of `bind()` function.
It would look something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var codeError; //Declare outside the scope of the function.

    $('#cognome').bind( 'blur',  function(){
        var cog = $(this).val();
        if(cog == "" || cog.length<=2) {
            $('#chkCognome' ).addClass("invalid").removeClass("valid"); 

            codeError=1;
        } else {
            $('#chkCognome').addClass("valid").removeClass("invalid");  

            codeError=0;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare `codeError` outside of the if statement, and potentially outside of your event binding as well, depending on what level you want it to be accessible at.

```
var codeError; // accessible within all subsequent functions and event handlers

$('#cognome').on('blur',  function(){
    if (cog === '') {
        codeError = 1;
    }
    else {
        codeError = 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
     <form action="error.php" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" value="0" name="code">
     </form> 
</html>    

<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {

          var codeError = $(input).val(0); 

          if(error) { $(input).val(1); }

     })
</script>
```

you need to define codeError outside of if else statement, better yet you don't really need a else statement.  if you need to pass it to php just use `<form>`